# Rotation won't stop until it gets back to default position Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a spaceship and I want to rotate it by pressing right and left arrow keys.

When ship is stable, it successfuly rotates and stops whenever i release the arrow keys.

But while the ship is in motion, it won't stop rotating until it gets back to its original position.

If I release before gets to 180 degrees, it goes back. If I release after 180 degrees, it completes the cycle.

How do I fix this? Here are some of the code blocks involved with this mechanic.

```
[SerializeField]public float rotationSpeed;
public bool isRotating = false;
public void Rotation()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        isRotating = true;
        transform.Rotate(0,0,-rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime,Space.World);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        isRotating = true;
        transform.Rotate(0,0,rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
    else {
        isRotating = false;
    }
}





 if ((force != Vector2.zero) && (shiprotatescript.isRotating == false)){
    shiprotatescript.Rotation();
    Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, force);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,toRotation,rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
```

Those two blocks are seperate scripts.

Have any idea? Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Remove the second script.

Comment: It works, but now ship won't rotate to its moving direction.